# embedded matlab function variable input errors

Tags: matlab, function

```
function [opt_st, u_pr, y_pr, cv_pr] = fcn( nu, ny, Np)

%#codegen

coder.extrinsic('mpc_ea');

opt_st = zeros(1);
u_pr = zeros(nu,Np+1);
y_pr = zeros(ny,Np+1);
cv_pr =zeros(1);

[opt_st, u_pr, y_pr, cv_pr] = mpc_ea;
```

When I run this function, it gives the error "Data 'u_pr' (#427) is inferred as a variable size matrix, while its specified type is something else.". What is the solution for this problem? I will be happy for helps.

Comment: Don't initialize any of your variables before doing `mpc_ea`.  Comment out the assignments for `opt_st`, `u_pr`, `y_pr` and `cv_pr` and run your code again (i.e. comment out the four lines between `coder.extrinsic('mpc_ea');` and `[opt_st, u_pr, y_pr, cv_pr] = mpc_ea;`

Comment: unfortunately, it does not help!

Comment: BTW, do not append the `embedded` tag to your post.  You are using it incorrectly.

Comment: What does `coder.extrinsic('mpc_ea');` return?  I'm not quite familiar with the MATLAB Code Generation process

Comment: it returns [opt_st, u_pr, y_pr, cv_pr].

Comment: How did you compile this code? i.e. What did you use for args? Which line does the error point to?

Comment: Try to delete the four lines `opt_st = zeros(1);
u_pr = zeros(nu,Np+1);
y_pr = zeros(ny,Np+1);
cv_pr =zeros(1);`, it should fix the problem.

Comment: @Daniel - I suggested that to the OP (well... I told the OP to comment those statements out).  Apparently it didn't work (that or the OP didn't do what I said properly).

Comment: @rayryeng: You are right, did not carefully read the comments.

Comment: @user3489173: If it did not help, what error message did you get without the lines?

Comment: @Daniel - Not a problem at all.  The OP wasn't quite clear as to why "it does not help" at all.

Comment: this is a very common problem:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74547-how-to-make-simulink-matlab-function-work  but still i was not able to solve it.